# How to run macros(.iim)one by one

Tags: imacros

I am new to imacros.I have 5 macros(.iim).i want to execute all macros one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript scripting.

```
iimPlay("macro1.iim")
iimPlay("macro2.iim")
iimPlay("macro3.iim")
iimPlay("macro4.iim")
iimPlay("macro5.iim")
```

The macros have to be in the Macros folder alongside #Current.iim  macro.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a loop and set the time that you want to run use this code con javascripting

```
var loopcounter = 10

for (i=1;i<=loopcounter;i++){
iimPlay("macro1.iim");
iimPlay("macro2.iim");
iimPlay("macro3.iim");
}
```